# Google ima3 Vast Ad is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, vast, google-ima

I have implemented following:

https://eas8.emediate.eu/eas?cu=20056;ty=video;pageviewid=_

Suddenly its stop working and returning 303 error. I am unable to identify the issue.

It is not working in following test environment too:
http://zutils.zedo.com/vastvalidator/#/vastInspector

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector

Answer (score 0):

303 means No Ads VAST response after one or more Wrappers.

Your VAST https://eas8.emediate.eu/eas?cu=20056;ty=video;pageviewid=_
is a wrapper to https://adx.adform.net/adx/?mid=118264&t=2
and adform serves an empty VAST root node, no ads. Maybe the campaign has been paused or stopped.

Comment: Can you guide, how can I cross-check it if campaign stopped.
As our partner asked us to make sure if it is integrated with ima3 SDK. Is it something related to that?

Comment: It is difficult to check from the outside whether a campaign has been stopped or nor because it's impossible to know or reliably manipulate all targeting parameters. Communications work best :-) Work your way down the chain and get in touch with your partner or Adform to make sure their tag is supposed to serve ads for you.